# Bad known_hosts file when connecting to loadbalanced domain

Tags: ssh

FOO.COM has two A records. 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2. If I connect to ssh root@FOO.com then it sometimes can connect, sometimes it writes that there is a key mismatch, update known_hosts file. So I know that what is causing this (the two IP address behind the domain..).. but how can I resolve it? And:

```
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

no, this shouldn't be the solution :D

Comment: Are 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 on the same physical back-end server?

Comment: 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 have different keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mv known_hosts known_hosts_old; ssh-keyscan FOO.com > known_hosts
```

it works

Comment: Won't that stop working the next time it gives you a different server?

Comment: What gives me different server? Please clarify :\ :D later I restored my old known_hosts file, but put the ssh-keyscan line back